# Solving an ODE , $y'-Ay=0$ where A is a matrix

Tags: differential-equations, matrix

I want to solve the following :

$y'-\mathcal{A}y=0$

here

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{A}=
\begin{vmatrix}
30, 64, 23\\
-11, -23, -9\\
-11, -23, -9
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}

So this would imply that it is a system of (simple) ODEs.

So I do the following

```
A = {{30, 64, 23}, {-11, -23, -9}, {6, 15, 4}}
eqn = DSolve[y'[x] - A*y[x] == 0, y[x], x]
```

But I get the error

""List encountered within..... There should be no lists on either side of the equations.""

So I tried "LinearSolve" instead,

```
eqn1 = LinearSolve[A]
```

But this gave just a weird icon, but no solutions.

This seems strange, since the matrix and the Dsolve syntax are correct.

Then I try to plot the solutions,

```
Plot[{y1[x] /.eqn, y2[x] /.eqn,  y3[x] /.eqn}, {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"solution", None}, {x, {y1[x], y2[x], y3[x]}}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"y1(x)", "y2(x)"}, "y3(x)"]
```

But this is empty. Indeed, the constant is not defined. But in order to define it I must use the rule that the plots are plotted along the curve that crosses the point (1,1,1).

This is a little hard to define.

Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: Look for `MatrixExp`

Comment: `y[t_] = MatrixExp[A t] . y[0]` as @UlrichNeumann says.

Comment: Note that `LinearSolve` is for solving algebraic equations not differential equations.

Comment: You want want ` DSolve[y'[x] - A.y[x] == 0, y[x], x]`. Note use of `Dot` instead of `Times`. Also `y` needs to be either an explicit vector, or declared as such (see responses).

Comment: Tried that, but  it gave no result, just the input command in a different font: A = {{30, 64, 23}, {-11, -23, -9}, {6, 15, 4}}
eqn = DSolve[y'[x] - A.y[x] == 0, y[x], x]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A = {{30, 64, 23}, {-11, -23, -9}, {6, 15, 4}}
depVar = {y1[x], y2[x], y3[x]}
ode = Thread[D[depVar, x] - A . depVar == 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now do

```
eqn = DSolve[ode, depVar, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update**

To plot the solution, need initial conditions. Here is an example

```
A = {{30, 64, 23}, {-11, -23, -9}, {6, 15, 4}}
depVar = {y1[x], y2[x], y3[x]}
(ode = Thread[D[depVar, x] - A . depVar == 0]) // Column
ic = {y1[0] == 1, y2[0] == 1, y3[0] == 1};
sol = DSolveValue[{ode, ic}, depVar, x];
Plot[sol, {x, 0, .1}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> {"y1(x)", "y2(x)", "y3(x)"}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The system is clearly unstable

Comment: Thanks for this. Why did you have to specifcy depvar?

Comment: @Vangsnes well, you have 3 dependent variables, since it is 3 by 3 matrix. So I just gave them some names to make it easier to write the ode. This is one way to do it. But for me. this is clear since I can see the odes' before calling `DSolve`

Comment: @Nasser Beat me to it. Nicely done (+1)

Comment: Nasser, I add an update

Comment: @Vangsnes for your update. You can't plot since you did not give initial conditions. if you know what the initial conditions you can add it to your question. You need a vector of 3 entries for the initial conditions.

Comment: Strange, I only have a point given and nothing else. I know that I have to plot the function in  the form: $g(x)=ln(y1^2+y2^2+y3^2)$. Also, the solution to the Solve was ONLY the real solution, maybe that will fix the problem

Comment: @Vangsnes will add a plot now.

Comment: depVar = {y1[x], y2[x], y3[x]};
ode = Thread[D[depVar, x] - Re[A . depVar] == 0];
eqn = DSolve[ode, depVar, x]

Comment: This is only for the Real part.

Comment: Thanks, I take the task was incomplete without some ICs. It's a weird problem.

Comment: @Vangsnes you need IC's to do the plot. Can't plot with unknowns in the solution.

Answer (score 3):

why not declare y[x] as a vector?

```
A = {{30, 64, 23}, {-11, -23, -9}, {6, 15, 4}};
eqn = DSolve[y'[x] - A . y[x] == 0, y[x] \[Element] Vectors[3], x]
```

the same result as by Nasser

Comment: As I mentioned, the way I did is not the only way, but by naming the dependent variables,  it does allow one to see the actual ode's before calling DSolve. This could be useful sometimes (may be for debugging)